# How do I solve this six-piece Burr puzzle that becomes a knot?

Tags: mechanical-puzzles, burr-puzzle

I've seen a few solutions to this problem on the site, but **none** of the pieces used in those solutions have the exact shape as the pieces I have.

[image: The pieces]
[image: The pieces]

This isn't the exact puzzle, so the colors do not match, but this is what the end result is supposed to look like:

[image: The end result]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rods are paired up as follows:

> Yellow and green
> Purple and Blue
> Red and Orange

There are no empty spaces when the puzzle is in its solved state.

While I do know the final configuration of the pieces, I can't quite visualise the puzzle well enough to be sure of the exact assembly sequence. So the following description may not work entirely.

> 1. Put the yellow and green together side by side, their hollow sides facing each other, and such that there is a large square opening between them into which eventually the final orange key piece will be inserted. Apart from the large square hole there are also smaller holes between them.
>  2. Put the red piece between the yellow and green pieces, filling those smaller holes.
>  3. The purple and blue pieces will now be clamped around the yellow and green such that the square opening is not blocked. However, the purple piece will need to fill the notch in the yellow piece, and to get it into position I think you will have to temporarily remove the green piece, put the purple in place, return the green piece, and only then place the blue piece.
>  4. Lastly, insert the orange key piece into the hole.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a Blender animation of the burr assembly, using the same colours as those in the photo:

> [image]
>  MP4 [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/247802651096514560/1029241964555665461/burr3.mp4), Blender scene [here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/247802651096514560/1029241725228699738/burr3.blend).

And some higher-res stills from the animation:

> [image]
>
>  [image]
>
>  [image]
>
>  [image]